# Why isn't Magento 2 recognizing my library in requirejs-config.js?

Tags: magento2, requirejs, requirejs-config.js

**This is Library location**

> app\design\frontend\user\theme\web\js\owl.carousel.min.js

**this is my config js file**

> app\design\frontend\user\theme\requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
deps: [
    "js/main"
],

map: {
    '*': {
        owlCarousel:'js/owl.carousel.min'
    }
},

shim: {
    jquery: {
        exports: '$'
    },

    'Magento_Catalog/js/price-box':
        {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },

    owlCarousel: ["jquery"]
}

};
```

**Inside**

> app\design\frontend\user\theme\web\js\main.js

```
define([
"jquery",
"owlCarousel"
], 

function($) {
"use strict";

if(typeof owlCarousel === 'function') { 
  console.log('owlCarousel is loaded');
}else{
  console.log('owlCarousel is NOT loaded');
}

});
```

**Inside phtml**

```
require(['jquery', 'owlCarousel'],function($, owlCarousel){
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            margin:10,
            nav:true,
            mouseDrag:false,
            navText : ["",""],
            rewindNav : true,
            responsive:{
                0:{
                    items:3
                },
                600:{
                    items:3
                },
                1000:{
                    items:3
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Result**

owlCarousel is NOT loaded

(index):1175 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).owlCarousel is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `jQuery` in your document.ready function use `$` instead since it is the one defined in your function.

Try this:

```
require(['jquery', 'owlCarousel'],function($, owlCarousel){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            margin:10,
            nav:true,
            mouseDrag:false,
            navText : ["",""],
            rewindNav : true,
            responsive:{
                0:{
                    items:3
                },
                600:{
                    items:3
                },
                1000:{
                    items:3
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```